# Completely different inferences between single-trial difference and meta-analysis comparison

Tags: meta-analysis, count-data, network-meta-analysis

I have the following data

> ```
>    mydat <- read.table(textConnection('
>    study treatment exposure responders
>        A         5      277         22
>        B         1     1251        211
>        B         5      625          8
>        C         5      477         36
>        C         7      236          6'), header=TRUE)
> ```

Each (study, treatment) combination produces a risk of `responders/exposure`. In study B, we see that the risk of Treatment 1 = `211/1251 = 0.169` and Treatment 5 = `8/625 = 0.013`, and this risk is significantly different based on a two-sample t-test for just Study B.

Trials A and C reveal risks for Treatment 5 to be `22/277 = 0.079` and `36/477 = 0.075` respectively, still far lower than the Treatment 1 in Study B (although I know, it's from a different trial so results aren't transferable). In any case, a direct comparison in Study B of Treatment 5 vs 1 shows significance, and additional trials still have far lower proportions, so it seems most likely that a network meta-analysis should reveal significance as well. Let's proceed with the network meta-analysis with package `gemtc`

> ```
>    require(gemtc)
>    net = mtc.network(mydat, treatments = data.frame(id = c(1, 5, 7), description = c("T1", "T2", "T3")))
>    model <- mtc.model(net, likelihood = "poisson", link = "log")
>    res <- mtc.run(model, n.iter = 100000, thin = 5)
>    leaguetab <- data.frame(round(exp(relative.effect.table(res)),2))
>    
>    leaguetab
>                         X1                 X5                X7
>    1                     1     0.07 (0, 1.81)    0.02 (0, 2.29)
>    5  13.83 (0.55, 346.05)                  5 0.32 (0.01, 8.45)
>    7 44.08 (0.44, 4544.36) 3.15 (0.12, 86.25)                 7
> ```

The risk ratio of Treatment 5 vs Treatment 1 is 0.07, but the confidence intervals don't show significance. Why is this so? I understand network meta-analysis handles trial hetereogeneity via random effects, but it still seems bizarre it's not significant, since a head-on comparison from Study B reveals significance. All MCMC diagnostics reveal no problems with the sampling either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model you are using is a random-effects model that allows for heterogeneity. But with two studies included in the analysis (study A is not even included, since it only has a single arm), there is essentially no information to estimate the amount of heterogeneity. So the heterogeneity prior essentially determines the posterior distribution for the heterogeneity parameter.

By default, `mtc.hy.prior("std.dev", "dunif", 0, "om.scale")` is used for the prior, so a uniform distribution on $\tau$ where the upper bound for the uniform distribution is determined based on the data (here `model$om.scale` is equal to around 2.5). The mean/median of a $U(0,2.5)$ distribution is 1.25. Now look at the output from `summary(res)` and you will find that the posterior mean/median (`sd.d`) is also 1.25. Also, all the other quantiles given for the posterior match up to what you would expect for such a uniform distribution (e.g., `punif(0.0644, 0, 2.5)` for the 2.5% quantile is about .025). So the posterior is essentially just the prior.

A mean/median amount of heterogeneity equal to 1.25 according to the posterior is a huge amount of heterogeneity for log incidence rates. Try fitting the model with a more restricted uniform prior:

```
model <- mtc.model(net, likelihood = "poisson", link = "log", hy.prior=mtc.hy.prior("std.dev", "dunif", 0, 1))
```

Now the CI for treatment 5 versus 1 is `0.07 (0.02, 0.29)` so 1 is not included in the CI and hence the difference is significant.

Comment: Nice answer! Since the prior uses the data to help determine the hyperparameters, would it be reasonable tor eally set the upper bound to equal 1 (instead of 2.5)? Perhaps the data really is just this heterogeneous?

Comment: With 2 studies, there is hardly any evidence to say whether the studies are really heterogeneous or not. A $\tau$ value of 1 implies that 95% of the true incidence rates (assuming a true log incidence rate of 0) lie between `exp(0 + c(-1,1)*1.96*1)` so 0.14 to 7.10. That's already a huge amount of heterogeneity. A value of 2.5 as an upper bound is really implausible.